# Как обеспечить уникальность каждой записи в сессию без функции time?

Tags: php, сессия

Из формы приходят данные (объявление), записываются в `$_POST`. Потом записываются в сессию:

```
$_SESSION['ad'][time()] = array(
    'private' => $_POST['private'], 'seller_name' => $_POST['seller_name'], 'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone'], 'location_id'=> $_POST['location_id'], 
    'metro_id' => $_POST['metro_id'], 'category_id'=> $_POST['category_id'], 
    'title' => $_POST['title'], 'description'=> $_POST['description'], 'price'=> $_POST['price']
);
```

Уникальность записи в сессию обеспечивается за счет функции `time()`. Но здесь одно "но": если два объявления поступили в одну и ту же секунду, запишется только одно объявление.

И, наконец, вопрос: как обеспечить уникальность каждого объявления без функции `time()`, или чем заменить функцию `time()`?

Comment: Вы предполагаете, что один пользователь будет присылать вам объявления чаще 1 раза в секунду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше использовать функцию uniqid(), она как раз предназначена для таких случаев.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий!

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не нравится функция `array_push()`, то попытайте счастья с `microtime()`.

Comment: Кажется, спросивший не понял сути предложенного решения, а оно хорошее! Пусть в сессии будет не ассоциативный массив. При поступлении нового объявления, его просто добавляют в хвост массива. Если нужен его уникальный id, тут же сохраните длину массива минус один: `$id = array_push( $_SESSION['ad'], array('private'=>...)) -1;`

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения. Я надеялся, что спросивший самостоятельно прочитает описание функции и дойдёт до решения. Это было бы полезнее с образовательной точки зрения. :)

Comment: Да действительно суть предложенного решения понял только после разъяснения. Уникальный id нужен для того, чтобы отправить его методом GET на др. страничку и извлечь (вывести на экран) объявление(с этим id) из массива $_SESSION. Подсказали еще одно решение. В коде вместо $_SESSION['ad'][time()] = array(...) будет $_SESSION['ad'][] = array(...)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$hash = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 8);
```